# Recompile decompiled apk file

Tags: java, android

I decompiled an apk file using **APKTool** and got java files using **dex2jar**.
I translated the application into my language and edited a text in java files.
Now, how I can recompile it?
And how I can sign recompiled apk?

Answer (score 0):

Use [sign.jar](https://github.com/appium/sign) which automatically signs an apk with the Android test certificate. Of course this means that the app is a "different" app from the original, since it's signed by a different authority, in this case, you

Comment: `since it's signed by a different authority, in this case, you`, just another  **thieve**, who **steals** someone else's work.

Comment: the illegitimate/legitimate use of this tool, is not something that is up to me to judge.  I choose to believe the story of the guy asking the question

Comment: @BobMalooga I don't steal someone else's work I just translate it.

Comment: @JuanCortes Thanks for answer. You answered my second question. Please answer my first question (if you can).

Comment: Open the app in Android Studio, build it, that will generate an apk inside the build folder. Use that in the tool linked above

Comment: @Gahem You are infringing the author's copyright. You have **no right** to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Use apk-editor
Is app in android to decompile and recompile

https://apk-editor.en.uptodown.com/android